# all() function; iterate through list inside if statement (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've been attempting to solve the "Project Euler" questions and got stuck on one of them.
I'm trying to iterate through a list and check if a given number can be divided evenly by each value in the given list.
i've tried the all() function, thinking that it's best, but not i either get a value error or nothing at all.
I've tried a lot of syntex combinations with the all() function but no luck.

```
div_lst = [x for x in range(1, 21)]
num_list = [x for x in range(1, 1000000)]

for x in num_list:
    if all(x % y for y in div_lst):
        print(x)
```

I've tried

```
all((x % y == 0) for y in div_lst) 
all((x % y for y in div_lst) == 0)
```

and lots more, just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you could reduce your first two lines to just `div_lst = range(1, 21)`... No need to iterate over `range` and create a list. `range` creates a list as it is.

Comment: wow thanks didn't know that, gonna save me some time.

Comment: Side question, say i wanted a list of only even numbers, i'de have to use [x for x in range(1, 1000) if x % 3 == 0] ?             or just create any list with some conditions from range?

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax

```
all((x % y == 0) for y in div_lst)
```

does what you want; it checks whether `x` is divisible by `y` for each `y` in `div_lst`.  The only reason you didn't get anything printed out is because the answer is much bigger than 10**6, and so you didn't try the right `x`.

By contrast, `all(x % y for y in div_lst)` is equivalent to `all((x % y != 0) for y in div_lst)`, which isn't what you want, and since all integers are congruent to 0 mod 1 has no solutions anyway.

(Hint: this isn't the right way to solve this problem.  Read up on "lowest common multiples", and how they can be computed.)

Comment: Exactly, the point of project Euler is that solving the problems by brute force takes too long, or too much memory. You have to think how to reduce the amount of loops, or even replace them completely.